# CkEditor does not update content when used in production mode

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, ckeditor

I am facing an issue using gwt-ckeditor in my app, in production mode when deployed on a webserver (tomcat).
I am loading content from database and displaying these content on to the ckeditor using -

```
ckeditor.setHTML(content);
```

This internally calls `setData()` of the ckeditor.js.

It works fine in hosted mode and the content are displayed, but when deployed in tomcat the editor is rendered but the data is not set to the editor.
For some reason it seems like the event setData which is executed internally in `setData()`, is not been fired.

Any help regarding the issue would be highly appreciated. Its been driving me crazy for couple of days.